# What is the difference between "glamorous" and "mesmerizing"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-difference

I looked up both "[glamorous](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/glamorous)" and "[mesmerizing](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mesmerizing)", but I am still not sure which one is the better adjective to explain *some beautiful eyes which are attractive and capture attention*:

- ... **glamorous** eyes ...
- ... **mesmerizing** eyes ...

Comment: Can you cite the specific definitions that are confusing you (with links)? The two *can* mean similar things but *primarily* mean quite different things.

Comment: @Catija: The links to Oxford dictionary are added.

Comment: But what about those definitions are confusing to you? Admittedly, they're pretty *bad* definitions. Try these: [glamorous](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/glamorous) and [mesmerizing](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/mesmerize). Does that help? The nice thing about Longman is that it's designed for learners, not for native speakers. I've found their definitions to be much better than many other sites.

Comment: @Catija: Thanks for the references. The mesmerizing definition says: "if you are mesmerized by someone or something, you cannot stop watching them". That's what I need to say to explain the eyes.

Comment: *glamour* has to do with beauty. *mesmerize* is more like a *trance*.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether you want to focus on the fact they are beautiful, or attention-grabbing and hard to look away from. In the first case you might want ***glamorous***, which once had connotations related to "magical" effects but now mostly means "the sort of appearance you expect from the rich and famous"; this tends to imply that things aren't entirely natural, however, and describing *eyes* as glamorous might cause some confusion in readers. They would possibly think you meant they were heavily made-up with mascara, eyeliner and eye shadow.

If the intent is that they grab attention and are hard to look away from, ***mesmerising*** is a good word choice. It suggests that one looking into the eyes tends to fall into a trance, but no-one would actually take that literally without something else pointing that way. It would usually be taken to mean that you find it hard to look away, that you feel as if you *could* fall into a trance looking into them.